# Nested FOR loops in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to impliment a nested FOR loop in excel. Then interior loop does not seem to be executing in the code. Is the error syntatical? What's going on here?

```
Sub Statistics()
    Dim cc As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 4
    cc = 0
    For cc = 0 To 4
        For i = 4 To -4
            If Sheets("Significance").Cells(4 + cc, 13 - i) = 1 Then Sheets("Output Database").Cells(8 + currevent, 7 + cc) = i
        Next i
    Next cc

        'Rates
    i = 4
    cc = 0
    For cc = 0 To 4
        For i = 4 To -4
            If Sheets("Significance").Cells(14 + cc, 13 - i) = 1 Then Sheets("Output Database").Cells(8 + currevent, 23 + cc) = i
        Next i
    Next cc    
End Sub
```

Comment: `For i = 4 To -4` will do nothing, `i` is `4` at the beginning, `4` is greater than `-4` so there is no iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop referring to the i variable needs to specify that i is decreasing:

```
For i = 4 To -4 Step -1
```